# How to do a Next.js Build and Export WIthout Minification and Optimization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How can I do a Next.js build and export without minifying and optimizing the output files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**For compression, you would open your `next.config.js` and set it to false:**

```
module.exports = {
  compress: false,
}
```

**And for minify, you would do it in your webpack.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 7):

`next.config.js`

```js
module.exports = (nextConfig) => {
  return {
    ...nextConfig,
    webpack(webpackConfig) {
      return {
        ...webpackConfig,
        optimization: {
          minimize: false
        }
      };
    }
  };
};
```

Using `next@^12.0.0` will produce unminified HTML, JS, and somewhat CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of @matt-jensen's answer with Typescript types:

`next.config.js`

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  // ...
  /**
   * @param {import('webpack').Configuration} webpackConfig
   * @returns {import('webpack').Configuration}
   */
  webpack(webpackConfig) {
    return {
      ...webpackConfig,
      optimization: {
        minimize: false,
      },
    };
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Comment: I had to install webpack as a dev dependency as well for this to work.