# NextJS hydration errors (Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have two errors only when the app is deployed, not in dev mode nor the local build, which is another issue altogether.

**1st error:** Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.

**2nd error:** There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.

I found out that the errors are caused by the formatting of the time that I get from an API in Unix timestamp format (current.dt), but I don't know how else to handle this. Should I format the date on the server i.e. in getServerSideProps? Or are these errors caused by something else?

**Edit**: Live app with errors: https://weather-test-mu.vercel.app/

*WeatherDisplay*:

```
import type { Current, Location } from '../../types/typeWeatherApi';

const WeatherDisplay = ({
    location,
    current,
}: {
    location: Location;
    current: Current;
}) => {
    // This causes the errors:
    const hour = ('0' + new Date(current.dt * 1000).getHours()).slice(-2);
    const minutes = ('0' + new Date(current.dt * 1000).getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    const currentTime = `${hour}:${minutes}`;

    return (
        <article>
            <h1>{location.name}</h1>
            <p>{location.country}</p>
            <p>{current.feels_like}</p>
            {/* This causes the error: */}
            <p>{currentTime}</p>
        </article>
    );
};

export default WeatherDisplay;
```

*Index page with getServerSideProps*:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState } from 'react';

import type { NextPage, GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import type { Data, Location } from '../types/typeWeatherApi';

import { getCurrentWeather } from './api/currentWeather';
import { getCurrentLocation } from './api/currentLocation';

import WeatherDisplay from '../components/weather-display/weather-display';

const Home: NextPage = ({ initialWeather, initialLocation }: any) => {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState<Location>(initialLocation);
    const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState<Data>(initialWeather);
    const [units, setUnits] = useState('metric');
    const [lang, setLang] = useState('en');

    const getGeolocationData = () => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                axios
                    .get(
                        `/api/currentLocation?lon=${position.coords.longitude}&lat=${position.coords.latitude}`
                    )
                    .then((response) => setLocation(response.data[0]));
            },
            (error) => {
                console.warn(`ERROR(${error.code}): ${error.message}`);
            },
            {
                timeout: 10000,
                maximumAge: 0,
            }
        );
    };

    const getCurrentWeather = async () => {
        await axios
            .get(
                `/api/currentWeather?lon=${location.lon}&lat=${location.lat}&units=${units}&lang=${lang}`
            )
            .then((response) => setWeatherData(response.data))
            .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    };

    return (
        <>
            <section>
                <div>
                    <p>Latitude: {location.lat}</p>
                    <p>Longitude: {location.lon}</p>
                </div>
                <button onClick={getGeolocationData}>Get Current Location</button>

                <button onClick={getCurrentWeather}>Get Current Weather</button>
            </section>
            <section className="current-weather">
                <WeatherDisplay location={location} current={weatherData.current} />
            </section>
        </>
    );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
    const defaultWeatherQuery = {
        lat: '51.5072',
        lon: '0.1276',
        exclude: '',
        units: 'metric',
        lang: 'en',
    };

    const defaultLocationQuery = {
        lat: defaultWeatherQuery.lat,
        lon: defaultWeatherQuery.lon,
    };

    const defaultWeather = await getCurrentWeather(defaultWeatherQuery);
    const defaultLocation = await getCurrentLocation(defaultLocationQuery);

    return {
        props: {
            initialWeather: defaultWeather,
            initialLocation: defaultLocation[0],
        },
    };
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: "use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings." (from the error) -> please do this

Comment: Thanks, I missed that in the error. Is the next.js dev environment set as minified as default? Because I haven't touched any settings like that, and I have a little problem to find how to "unminify" dev enviroment.

Comment: [Disable minify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68916202/19330634)

Comment: So I did disable minify, but I still got no errors. The errors are shown only when the app is deployed on vercel or netlify.

Comment: Please join [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246123/next-js-hydration-issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an answer from [GitHub discussions](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/38263) on next.js, I will paste it here for anyone facing the same problem as me:

Quote [icyJoseph](https://github.com/icyJoseph):

> Hi,
>
> Yeah so this two errors are combined.
>
> Because the client, on the first frame, needs to see the same HTML as
> the server sent over, in order to place event listeners and place
> siblings and children correctly, if there's an error while this is
> being done, React logs an error. This has happened all the way back to
> React 17 AFAIK.
>
> Problem number 2 kicks in with the new rendering root, which sees this
> as a rendering error, which is unfriendly to concurrent features, so
> hydration fails and it throws the entire thing out the window.
>
> At least that's how I interpret the second error. Lots of people just
> ignored error number 1, during the entire 2 years React 17 was out,
> not saying you did, but many use libraries that did, and others just
> ignored them. Possible work around
>
> Time and randomness are two of the things that most commonly produce
> this.
>
> I would attack this problem like this:
>
> 1. Let the server render the time, but in UTC format
> 2. Optionally, put CSS that makes this hidden, but still present on the layout (not display none)
> 3. From the client, update to the correct time zone, also make the time visible
>
> ```
> import { CSSProperties, useEffect, useState } from "react";
> import { Example } from "../components/Example";
>
> const TimeDisplay = ({ time }: { time: number }) => {
>   const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(() => {
>     const hour = ("0" + new Date(time * 1000).getUTCHours()).slice(-2);
>     const minutes = ("0" + new Date(time * 1000).getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2);
>
>     return `${hour}:${minutes} UTC`;
>   });
>
>   useEffect(() => {
>     setCurrentTime(() => {
>       const hour = ("0" + new Date(time * 1000).getHours()).slice(-2);
>       const minutes = ("0" + new Date(time * 1000).getMinutes()).slice(-2);
>
>       return `${hour}:${minutes}`;
>     });
>   }, [time]);
>
>   // optionally make this content take space, but remain invisible, to avoid layout shifts
>   // it's better to use a CSS class instead
>   const style: CSSProperties = {
>     visibility: currentTime.includes("UTC") ? "hidden" : "visible",
>   };
>
>   return (
>     <article>
>       <p style={style}>{currentTime}</p>
>     </article>
>   );
> };
> ```
>
> I'd recommend also mixing in the DateTimeFormat API,
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat,
> which can take care of showing the time zone for you:
>
> ```
> const date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0, 200));
>
> options = {
>   hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric', 
>   timeZoneName: 'short' 
> };
>
> console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('sv-SE', options).format(date));
> ```
>
> If I run the above on a [repl](https://replit.com/languages/javascript), I get 3:00:00 AM UTC (this would be
> what your server sends), but if I run it on the browsers I get,
> 4:00:00 CET.
>
> The source code of you page contains the time seen by the server.
>
> Since users arrive to you from different time zones, you have to
> account for a frame where you show UTC, and then you show the time for
> the users time zone. Combining this with CSS visibility is good,
> because you can avoid layout shifts and such, the time will take its
> place, but it won't be visible.
>
> Robots, crawlers still see the time, and for users with JS disabled,
> you could add a  tag that makes the date visible again.

Comment: Link to the comment seems broken